# Update QGraphicsScene from another, non-main thread

Tags: qt, concurrency, qgraphicsscene

I'm pretty new to QT's graphic view frame, and I couldn't find anything about this in the docs or on Google.

I have a GUI application that draws a representation for some data. The application itself does some work with matrices / vectors (a neural net thing) and has to represent it on a `QGraphicsScene`. So far so good, but I've noticed that the app segfaults & crashes sooner or later (and usually sooner) if I try to update the `QGraphicsScene` from another thread. The QT Docs say nothing about thread-safety & Google gives nothing. What I want (and pretty much need) to do is run the calculations & update the GUI representation accordingly, but the GUI controls etc themself have to remain responsive. As I said, my first thought was to do the whole thing in another thread, but it crashes randomly if I try to.

Is there any "accepted practice" to do this kind of thing in QT or is there some gotcha that I don't know of in the graphics view framework itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt docs actually say [quite a lot about thread safety](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/threads-reentrancy.html#thread-safe). If the docs for `QGraphicsScene` don't say anything it's because they are not thread-safe, consistent with the behaviour you are seeing.

What you need to do is run your calculations in another thread and synchronise that thread with the main GUI thread as appropriate. A simple way to do this would be to set a flag in the main thread when the calculations are ready for display. That way you can call the appropriate `QGraphicsScene` methods in the main thread at the right time by simply checking the flag.

Comment: Oh, didn't know the QT docs are that way, sorry. Kindof used to javadocs, they usually had it explicitly stated. Anyway, do you know of a way around this then?

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to synchronise between the two threads. The way you are doing it now you could be calling a `QGraphicsScene` method in one thread whilst the same `QGraphicsScene` instance is in the middle of executing the same or another of its methods in the other thread. Think of the possible carnage!